# Angular Promise .then() return value

Tags: angular, typescript

```
bbb(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(data => {
          resolve(data)
        },
         error => {
          reject(error);
        },
      );
    });
  }

ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log(//THIS LINE
      this.bbb().then(son => {
      return son;
    }));
  }
```

-This line- return ZoneAwarePromise in console. How can i return son's value?

Comment: But it's best to learn how to work with `Observable`s.

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I want to get Latitude and Longitude value from my API. After getting operation, i want to use that variable in another function to create map icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better practise is to use `Observable`:

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

bbb() {
 return this.http.get(this.url)
   .pipe(
     catchError(err => {
       console.log('err', err);
       return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
     });
}
```

And, then simply just subscribe to `bbb`:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

testSubscription: Subscription;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.testSubscription = this.bbb()
      .subscribe(son => {
        console.log('son', son); // here you get the result
      });
}
```

Don't forget to `unsubscribe`:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.testSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

If you still want to use `Promise`:

```
bbb() {
  return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise();
}
```

To get the result of `bbb`:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
   this.bbb()
     .then(son => {
       console.log('son', son); // here you get the result
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
     });
}
```

Comment: Can i reach son variable in any function? Because i have to create map icon on googlemaps.

Comment: You'll get `son` asyncroniously (after some time)...so if you want to use it in some function, call that function after you'll get the result (inside of `subscription` callback or  `than`)

Comment: Good that you're mentioning the observable way, but (1) `catchError` has to return an Observable and (2) the `$` suffix is usually only used for Observables but not Subscriptions.

Comment: @fridoo good notice! corrected that part